# Not able to load the Image from facebook response

Tags: facebook-login, auth0

I'm using Auth0 api for login. I have received facebook response in which user profile picture is as below:-

```
https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1324218274262199&height=50&width=50&ext=1525319136&hash=AeSrHdLSZSZhBkyQ
```

But when I'm trying to refer this image as below, I'm not able to retrieve the image.

```
<img src="https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1324218274262199&amp;height=50&amp;width=50&amp;ext=1525319136&amp;hash=AeSrHdLSZSZhBkyQ">
```

Any can give me any expert advice why its happening.? I'm not able to find any related docs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the image by calling the `picture` attribute from your user object. So for example, we can use the `access_token` we receive upon authentication to call the [`/userinfo` endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#change-password) to get the user profile (this information is returned as a JSON object) at which point we can do something like `userProfile.picture`. If you are still having trouble can you please share your code?